# How to cancel the insertion of records (create_record;) in Oracle Forms? Like a cancel button

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm having a problem in cancelling a DML. I'm a beginner in PL/SQL, sorry.

My program is this. In runtime, there's an add button where you can add records. but what if I pressed the add button, and decided to cancel it. so there must be a cancel button to cancel the operation. but i'm confused about the statement. Anyone knows what to write in the cancel button? its like cancelling the operation of create_record. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try `CLEAR_RECORD;`